# Woocommerce: get the shiping postal code to calculate shipping cost

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a new shipping method that calculates the rate based on the package weight, volume and customers zip code...
Ive had no problem retrieving the cart information on the calculate_shipping function, but when I try to retrieve the zip code from customer it seems to return an empty value.
how can I retrieve this information on runtime in order to calculate the final cost?

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) { 
    GLOBAL $woocommerce; 
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); 
    $cliente = $woocommerce->customer;  
    $peso = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight; 
    $customer_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode(); 
}
```

Solved:

```
$customer_postcode = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_postcode', true );
```

Comment: Can you please show us some of your code? You say that it returns "an empty value", we can't help fixing that without seeing the code.

Comment: yes of course:  <br/>

public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {  <br/>

   GLOBAL $woocommerce;  <br/>
     $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();  <br/>
     $cliente = $woocommerce->customer;  <br/>         
     $peso = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;  <br/>
        $customer_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();  <br/>

    }  <br/>  <br/> the $customer_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode(); is empty, the only way i can get this to work is if i go to checkout page and return to cart

Comment: We should never see a solution edited into the question body -- that is what answers are for.  Question details should not be posted as comments.

Answer (score 10):

```
// add this in your calculate_shipping function
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
     //remove the first bracket at the end of $postal_code
     $postal_code = $package[ 'destination' ][ 'postcode' ];
}
```

Comment: This is correct ans, get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_postcode', true ); is a wrong approach actually.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is handled in the customer class

billing post code

`WC()->customer->get_postcode();`

or

shipping post code

`WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();`

Comment: i had the same thought.... but it seems it does not load the customers shipping data until you get to checkout page...so basically right now the only way i can get this to work is if i go to checkout page and return to cart

Answer (score 1):

```
global $woocommerce;
$customer = new WC_Customer();
$woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce; 
$customer = new WC_customer();
$customer_id = $customer->ID

$get_customer_shipping_pincode = get_user_meta($customer_id,"shipping_postcode",true);
$get_customer_billing_pincode = get_user_meta($customer_id,"billing_postcode",true);
```

if user is logged in(for register user),

```
$get_customer_shipping_pincode = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"shipping_postcode",true);
$get_customer_billing_pincode = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"billing_postcode",true);
```